# How to register pressing F2 on the MC75a in C#?

Tags: c#, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to register a button press of the button F2 on the MC75a hand held terminal by Motorola/Zebra/Symbol. But it doesn't recognise the blue button press which is required to press F2. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is on your form. So if you have a windows form-project and a textbox is focused you could handle the keypress event of this control. If you have no focused controls, set your form to "keypreview = true". You can find this option in the settings of the form editor.

After enabling keypreview you can handle the keypress event from the form. This should work.

If you already enabled keypreview and it does not work, please make a test-form where you can see the keycodes which are send. There is a possibility to remap the keyboard of motorola devices.